# Learn to use Unit testing and Nunit application

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I need to start using unit tests in my code . The problem is that i never written unit tests . Can you please recommend me  some good sites and book how to write correctly unit tests and to use nunit application .

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good C# Unit testing book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509445/good-c-unit-testing-book)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend you get [The Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/) by Roy Osherove

Comment: This book is available for on-line reading with "Safari Books Online"

Answer (score 5):

I think [Pragmatic Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514020) is a good complementary book for Osherove's Art of Unit Testing.  Pragmatic unit testing deals with flushing out errors and different types of targeted testing, whereas Roy's book is a higher level and more general book that deals with a wider range of concepts.

As a beginner, I found the Pragmatic book an excellent starting point.

Here are some other quality resources:

[Misko's guide to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/).  One of the main battles when writing tests is ... how to structure code to make it testable.  Misko's guides are invaluable.

[Roy Osherove's cranky test review videos](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/tags/TestReview/default.aspx).  The second battle we face is writing good, clear, maintainable tests.  It's really easy to write bad/brittle/unmaintainable tests, so it is important to be aware of common mistakes.  These videos can be a bit cranky at times, but they're full of good tips.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little dated, but the one I started with was [Test Driven Development In Microsoft.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619484).